# Is there a way I can resolve this x-axis error?

Tags: r

I have just plotted ROC with the code lines below but the ROC graph is showing floating number as the scale on the x-axis. Please how do I resolve it?

```
    set.seed(1234)
    partROC <- sample(1:52885, 37000, replace = F)
    training <- Norm_Data[partROC,]
    testing <- Norm_Data[-partROC,]
    fitRand <- randomForest(marker~., data=training, method="class")
    fitPred <- predict(fitRand, testing, type = "class")
    ROCpred <-table(prediction=fitPred, actual=testing$marker)
    ROCprob <- predict(fitRand, testing, type = "prob")
    plot(roc(testing$marker, ROCprob[,2]), legacy.axes=TRUE, main = "ROC PLOT")
```

[image]

Comment: You need to include the packages you used, and a way to generate `Norm_Data`.  As it is, your code is not reproducible, so people aren't going to be able to try things to fix it.

Comment: recommend to use `ggplot2` as it comes with many functions to control axis behaviour.

Comment: pacman::p_load(pacman, caret, tidyr, ggplot2, plotly, 
               tidyverse, dplyr, caretEnsemble, rpart, randomForest, e1071, klaR, MASS, caTool)

Comment: those were the packages I installed